# Mac OS X Snow Leopard - Error CNQL2410_ClassicNotSeize.kext was installed improperly

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, kext

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
The system extension CNQL2410_ClassicNotSeize.kext was installed improperly.
```

I'm not sure what is triggering the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Canon site.

They have uploaded some new Snow Leopard (10.6) compatible drivers as at 9 September 2009.

Seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening on my Mac too, I think it's something to do with the Canon Scan Gear software and a PowerPC component that won't run because the default installation of Snow Leopard doesn't include Rosetta?

I haven't tried this yet but either install Rosetta (a dialogue will ask you to do this is you launch a PPC app) or see if you can find a Snow Leopard compatible scanner driver on the Canon site.

Comment: Yeah I've got the Canon Scan Gear software installed also.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, i just got the same error message while installing an updated Line6 driver and i do have Rosetta installed. i do also have a CanoScan LIDE scanner and what little turns up on Google suggests that this may the source of the problem.  why installing a Line6 driver triggered for me, though, i do not know.  possibly a freakish coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in installing Xcode from the Snow Leopard CD.  No problem reported when i upgraded the OS to 10.6, and am running Rosetta.

Also have CanoScan LiDE driver and CanoScan tools installed. They've never worked well; however, Image Capture does work well with my model (500F) and has all the features i was able to access with the Canon tools before Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

the same message appears after the installation of Vodafone Mobile Broadband 3.04.06.00 GMC on my MacBook (and it don't work with Snow Leopard ...)
adriano
p.s. I also have a Canoscan LIDE 500 F
p.p.s. installing the old Vodafone Mobile Connect I obtained 5 (!!!) Kernel panic ... so, do you know if exists an universal drive for Huawei E272 ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Canon issue. I too have the CanoScan LIDE 500F and Snow Leopard – however I didn't have any problems installing Snow Leopard, but just now I installed iTunes 9 and got two errors; "System extension can not be used" for both /System/Library/Extensions/CNQL2410_ClassicNotSeize.kext and /System/Library/Extensions/XEROX USB Printing.kext

Answer (score 0):

This is so weird. I got my 500F working - finally - after installing 10.6 by going into CanoScan and simply *looking* at the Settings dialog. Once I clicked 'OK' the scanner was recognised and I could use it. Before, nada.